# CentOS Shell Scripting elif error

Tags: bash, shell, scripting, centos, centos6

I cant get this script to work, returns error arround the first elif, can anyone help me pls ?

```
#!/bin/sh

/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/ffmpeg -i $1$2 -s qvga -vcodec libx264 -acodec aac -strict experimental -ab 64k -ac 2 -ar 44100 -f mp4 -b 384k -r 25 -movflags faststart $1com_$2
if [ "$6" = "Portrait" ]
then
/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/ffmpeg -i $1$3 -vf 'transpose=1' -y -strict -2 $1$4

elif [ "$6" = "LandscapeRight" ]
then
/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/ffmpeg -i $1$3 -vf 'vflip [a]; [a] hflip' -strict -2 -y $1$4

elif [ "$6" = "PortraitUpsideDown" ] &&  [ "$7" = "Iphone" ]
then
/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/ffmpeg -i $1$3 -vf -filter_complex 'transpose=2; vflip [a]' -y -strict -2 $1$4

elif [ "$6" = "PortraitUpsideDown" ] &&  [ "$7" = "Android" ]
then
/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/ffmpeg -i $1$3 -vf 'transpose=3' -y -strict -2  $1$4
fi


/var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/ffmpeg -itsoffset -1 -i $1$4 -vcodec mjpeg -vframes 1 -an -f rawvideo -strict -2 $1$5
echo $5
```

And im calling the file like this:

```
sh test.sh /var/www/vhosts/website/httpdocs/public/upload/album_detail_files/6501/ 201503131239571426307580.mp4 com_201503131239571426307580.mp4 LandscapeLeft_com_201503131239571426307580.mp4 1_20150313123957snap.jpg LandscapeLeft Iphone
```

The error is :

```
test.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'est.sh: line 7: `elif [ "$6" = "LandscapeRight" ]
```

Thans a lot ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
test.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `elif'
'est.sh: line 7: `elif [ "$6" = "LandscapeRight" ]
```

See how the single quote is overwriting the first character? That indicates  you have CRLF line endings, and your actual code is:

```
elif [ "$6" = "LandscapeRight" ]\r
```

Try running your script through `dos2unix`